# PHP pass variable after form is submitted

Tags: php, post, header, variables

I have a form that posts to process.php. Process.php send all the data to mysql then returns back to the page using:

```
<?php header("Location: /campaigns"); ?>
```

On the page it returns to I want to display a message saying form submitted. Can I post a variable to the Location: /campaigns. And use the variable to display the message (or modal box)? and if so what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do that, but here you got two most popular

### 1. Using GET

Just add GET variable to your URL that inform that the forum has been submitted successful:

```
header('Location: /campaigns?success=1');

...

if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == true) {
    echo 'Hurra!';
}
```

### 2. Using session variables

```
$_SESSION['success'] = true;
header('Location: /campaigns');

...

if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] == true) {
    echo 'Hurra!';
}
```

Comment: If you submit success=1, you shouldn't check $_GET['success'] == true, you should check $_GET['success'] == 1.

Comment: @Charles AFAIK, it will return false :)

Comment: @Charles: There could be "1", 1, "true", true - PHP is weak-typed language. But the most proper would be '1', cause every GET variable is a string.

Comment: While the check against true will cast the one to a boolean for the purposes of the comparison, your code is no longer clear and obvious as a result.  Any value that casts to boolean true will be acceptable, and that may be undesired behavior later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a get parameter, like `/campaigns?message=Your%20stuff%20was%20saved%20successfully%2E` that you then evaluate in `campaigns.php`. But be careful: The user can write whatever he wants in that parameter, so you should html escape it etc.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better have that variable in place. 
Sessions is another option, a cleaner one.